# alternate coordinate repetition from the list

Tags: list-manipulation, data

The output of this code repeats every x coordinate except last node. But I want to print the coordinate in such a way that coordinate at every odd position should be repeated except last node.

```
L=1000;   
nel = 3; t = 9;
    f[x_] := E^(-((-2000 + 0.5 (-t + 2 x))^2/139392));
    ActCoorX = Range[0, L, L/(2*nel)]
    q = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, Most@Riffle[ActCoorX, ActCoorX]}]
```

Output from the code above,

```
{{0, 3.02914*10^-13}, {0, 3.02914*10^-13}, {1666.67, 0.440969}, {1666.67, 0.440969}, {3333.33, 3.15079*10^-6}, {3333.33, 
  3.15079*10^-6}, {5000, 1.10497*10^-28}, {5000, 
  1.10497*10^-28}, {6666.67, 1.90197*10^-68}, {6666.67, 
  1.90197*10^-68}, {8333.33, 1.60686*10^-125}, {8333.33, 
  1.60686*10^-125}, {10000, 6.66306*10^-200}}
```

Expected is,

```
{{0., 3.44717*10^-13}, {0., 3.44717*10^-13}, {1666.67, 
  0.450628}, {3333.33, 2.89131*10^-6}, {3333.33, 
  2.89131*10^-6}, {5000., 9.10526*10^-29}, {6666.67, 
  1.40738*10^-68}, {6666.67, 1.40738*10^-68}, {8333.33, 
  1.0677*10^-125}, {10000., 3.97568*10^-200}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ActCoorX
```

> ```
> {0, 500/3, 1000/3, 500, 2000/3, 2500/3, 1000}
> ```

You can use the three-argument of form of `Riffle` as follows:

The elements in odd-numbered positions are `ActCoorX[[;; ;; 2]]`. To insert these in the desired positions of `ActCoorX` we use `{2,-3, 3}` in the third argument of `Riffle` (every third position starting from position 2 up to the 3rd-from-last (`-3`) position):

```
Riffle[ActCoorX, ActCoorX[[;; ;; 2]], {2, -3, 3}]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 500/3, 1000/3, 1000/3, 500, 2000/3, 2000/3, 2500/3, 1000}
> ```

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. Could you please the explain the syntax? [[;; ;; 2]], {2, -3, 3}]

Comment: @user75507 `[[;; ;; 2]]` is `Part` ,`{2, -3, 3}` is `Riffle` 's parm,

Comment: @user75507, added some explanation.